# applying onDestroy apps

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-lifecycle

I want to call a method onDestroy to make my apps whenever I kill it and when open the apps still shown the activity I want. But, when I'm applying the onDestroy still nothing happen and didn't show the activity I wanted. What I'm trying to do is make the apps still load the data. Tell me a way, to execute this method. I want to know every detail for my final project.

Here is my activity

```
   public class ChooseJob extends AppCompatActivity {

            public RecyclerView recyclerView;
            public RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;

            FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<BothJobs, OrderViewHolder> adapter;

            private FirebaseDatabase database;
            private DatabaseReference request;
            private DatabaseReference history;


            //string Intent
            String cName;
            String cPhone;
            String idJob;
            String cImage;
            String cAirport;
            String cAirlines;
            String cLuggage;
            String fDetail;
            String currentTime;
            String cPlace;  

            TextView orderLayout;


            MaterialSpinner spinner;
            TextView id;

            APIService mService;



            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_choose_job);


                mService = Common.getFCMService();
                database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
                request = database.getReference("RequestDetail");
                history = database.getReference("History");


                recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.listOrders);
                recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
                layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);


                callIntent();


                if (getIntent() != null)
                    loadOrders();


            }


            @Override
            protected void onDestroy() {
                super.onDestroy();

                callIntent();
                if (getIntent() != null)

                {
                    loadOrders();
                } else {


                    Toast.makeText(this, "Nothing HAPPEN!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }


            }

            private void callIntent() {

                Intent idJobCarrier = getIntent();
                idJob = idJobCarrier.getStringExtra("id");

                Intent phoneCarrier = getIntent();
                cPhone = phoneCarrier.getStringExtra("carrierPhone");

                Intent nameCarrier = getIntent();
                cName = nameCarrier.getStringExtra("carrierName");

                Intent imageCarrier = getIntent();
                cImage = imageCarrier.getStringExtra("carrierImage");

                Intent airportCarrier = getIntent();
                cAirport = airportCarrier.getStringExtra("carrierAirport");

                Intent airlinesCarrier = getIntent();
                cAirlines = airlinesCarrier.getStringExtra("carrierAirlines");

                Intent locationCarrier = getIntent();
                cPlace = locationCarrier.getStringExtra("carrierLocation");

                Intent luggageCarrier = getIntent();
                cLuggage = luggageCarrier.getStringExtra("carrierLuggage");

                Intent flightDetails = getIntent();
                fDetail = flightDetails.getStringExtra("flightDetails");

                Intent timeStampt = getIntent();
                currentTime = timeStampt.getStringExtra("saveCurrentDate");

            }

            private void loadOrders() {


                adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<BothJobs, OrderViewHolder>(
                        BothJobs.class,
                        R.layout.ob_task,
                        OrderViewHolder.class,
                        request.orderByChild("placeSend").equalTo(cPlace)
                ) {
                    @Override
                    protected void populateViewHolder(OrderViewHolder viewHolder, BothJobs model, final int position) {


                        viewHolder.tvId.setText("ID : " + adapter.getRef(position).getKey());
                        viewHolder.tvName.setText("Company Name : " + model.getCompanyName());
                        viewHolder.tvStatus.setText("Status : " + Common.convertCodeToStatus(model.getStatus()));
                        viewHolder.tvLocation.setText("Location To send : " + model.getPlaceSend());
                        viewHolder.tvWeight.setText("Weight : " + model.getWeight());


                        viewHolder.btn_edit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {


                                // showUpdateDialog(adapter.getRef(position).getKey(), adapter.getItem(position));
                                // Toast.makeText(ChooseJob.this, "OK BOS.. aku mau ni job", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            }
                        });

                    }
                };
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);


            }
```

Comment: What does `loadOrders()` do? Also, note there's no guarantee that `onDestroy()` will be called - `onPause()` is much more reliable (though also called more frequently)

Comment: you can not call intent from OnDestroy() method

Comment: The load orders will be load all the all the list on the recycler view.. all i want.. when im kill the apps.. the apps still running activity if i already kill the apps..

Comment: The call intent is extra string that i get from before activity..

Comment: Please clarify your question. It isn't clear what you are trying to do. `onDestroy()` may or may not be called when the `Activity` is destroyed. Please explain the scenario you are trying to cover and what doesn't work as expected.

Comment: i already put my code..

Comment: I don't want to see more code. I want to understand what you expect to happen? What isn't working? Your question is not understandable.

Comment: Im expecting when in A activity.. then go to B activity. For some reason maybe the apps was killed or the phone die suddenly, when im open the apps.. the B activity will show 1st.. not  the A activity.

Comment: You are executing code to do stuff in `onDestroy()`. That won't work. `onDestroy()` is called when your `Activity` is done. All you are supposed to do in `onDestroy()` is clean up and release resources. That's it. Your `Activity` is no longer active, so it is pointless to do anything.

Comment: Please add your manifest to your question and indicate which is the A `Activity` and which is the B `Activity` and how you transition from A to B.